# Curl .tgz package from web to local directory

Tags: curl

I try to download tgz file to the local linux machine.

```
curl -u user:pass -H "Content-Type: application/x-tar+gzip" https://arm....../artifactory/..../file.tgz -o /local_dir/file.tgz
```

When I try helm command with downloaded file,i am facing an error.

```
Error: file 'local_dir/file.tgz' does not appear to be a gzipped archive; 
got 'application/octet-stream'
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Could you please share the 'helm' command used?

Comment: helm upgrade --install deep-dive---debug --timeout 1200 --namespace deep-dive -f /local_dir/dive.yaml -f /local_dir/global.yaml local_dir/file.tgz

Comment: And what does `file local_dir/file.tgz` return? In the future, please don't reply with code in comments. That should be part of your original question. Good luck.